# com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: Invalid JSON

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I am new in the arcgis runtime. I am trying to develop an android application.

Steps that i follwed

- Created an account in arcgis.com .
- Then i created one Feature Layer (hosted) from the shape files zip .
- Then i share this to everyone.
- I copied the url given at the below. url [is](https://services7.arcgis.com/7FyZZrSIYfiWYztL/arcgis/rest/services/MyGisFileTest/FeatureServer) . Please see the output for the url.
- Then i try to implemet means to show this in the map on my android application And trying to do some feature-layer-query.Refference [is](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/feature-layer-query) in the GITHUB
- I am trying to replace the service_url to my [url](https://services7.arcgis.com/7FyZZrSIYfiWYztL/arcgis/rest/services/MyGisFileTest/FeatureServer). I am doing the search operation and getting the result from the online then trying to zoom that extent. But is noe even showing my map too.
- Now i am getting problem. it showing the error in

  > 05-10 16:31:23.516 20030-20030/com.esri.arcgisruntime.samples.featurelayerquery E/Feature layer query: Feature search failed for: kulathoor. Error=com.esri.arcgisruntime.ArcGISRuntimeException: Invalid JSON

Please see the below image for ref [image]

My code try

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // inflate MapView from layout
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        // create a map with the topographic basemap
        final ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.createTopographic());
        // set the map to be displayed in the mapview
        mMapView.setMap(map);

        // create feature layer with its service feature table
        // create the service feature table
        //mServiceFeatureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable(getResources().getString(R.string.sample_service_url));
        mServiceFeatureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable("https://services7.arcgis.com/7FyZZrSIYfiWYztL/arcgis/rest/services/MyGisFileLayerTest/MapServer");
        // create the feature layer using the service feature table
        mFeaturelayer = new FeatureLayer(mServiceFeatureTable);
        mFeaturelayer.setOpacity(1.0f);
        //override the renderer
        SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol= new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.RED, 1);
        SimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.YELLOW, lineSymbol);
        mFeaturelayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(fillSymbol));

        // add the layer to the map
        map.getOperationalLayers().add(mFeaturelayer);

        // zoom to a view point of the USA
        mMapView.setViewpointCenterAsync(new Point(-11000000, 5000000, SpatialReferences.getWebMercator()), 100000000);
    }
```

Can you find out where i am doing mistake . Why the may is not shwing in my app. Below is the screen shot of my application.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your FeatureServer url to the layer id, https://services7.arcgis.com/7FyZZrSIYfiWYztL/ArcGIS/rest/services/MyGisFileTest/FeatureServer/0.  Here is some updated code:

```
    ArcGISMap map = new ArcGISMap(Basemap.Type.STREETS_VECTOR, 8.498151, 76.929790, 10);
    // set the map to be displayed in this view
    mMapView.setMap(map);
        ServiceFeatureTable serviceFeatureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable("https://services7.arcgis.com/7FyZZrSIYfiWYztL/ArcGIS/rest/services/MyGisFileTest/FeatureServer/0");
    FeatureLayer featureLayer = new FeatureLayer(serviceFeatureTable);
    featureLayer.setOpacity(1.0f);
    SimpleLineSymbol lineSymbol= new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.BLACK, 1);
    SimpleFillSymbol fillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.Style.SOLID, Color.YELLOW, lineSymbol);
    featureLayer.setRenderer(new SimpleRenderer(fillSymbol));

    map.getOperationalLayers().add(featureLayer);
```

Comment: thans dr it is working fine.